# How to SUM datetime hours between integer and datetime in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, datetime, datagridview, datetimepicker

I have a datagridview with columns like below:

| Duration (hours) | Datetime1 | Datetime2 |

| 12 | 2020-8-10 8:00 | ? |

| 28 | 2020-8-13 8:00 | ? |

The value of the *Datetime2* is the sum of the hours between the *Duration* and *Datetime1*, and the format should be "yyyy-mm-dd H:mm". Is it possible to do the operation and put it in the *Datetime2* column?

*Note: the available time is from 8.00-16.00, so if the result of the sum is above 16.00, the date will increase and start from 8.00*

The result that I want to expect is like this:

| Duration (hours) | Datetime1 | Datetime2 |

| 12 | 2020-8-10 8:00 | **2020-8-11 12:00** |

| 27 | 2020-8-13 8.00 | **2020-8-17 11:00** |

Any helps are appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop over your data source, use Double.TryParse ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse)) if the first column's type is not a Double, use DateTime.TryParse ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse)) if the second column's type is not a DateTime, use DateTime.AddHours ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.addhours#System_DateTime_AddHours_System_Double_)) passing the value from column 1 to the value from column 2.

Here is an example:

```vb
For Each row In DataGridView1.Rows
    If (Not row.IsNewRow) Then
        Dim hoursToAdd As Double
        Dim dateFrom As DateTime
        If (Double.TryParse(rows.Cells(0).Value, hoursToAdd) AndAlso DateTime.TryParse(rows.Cells(1).Value, dateFrom)) Then
            Dim dateTo = dateFrom.AddHours(hoursToAdd)
            row.Cells(2).Value = dateTo.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd H:mm")
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Oh my God, it works.. thank you so much friend. You're nice person

Comment: How can I set the limitations for the hours? The limit is 08.00-16.00 and i want to excluding Saturday and sunday. Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: I’d open a separate question since the two are unrelated.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a newbie in this forum. Should I make a new question for the answer? Hehe